# Good way to store data based on user listed as a string?

Tags: java, string, data-structures

I have an arraylist of strings. The strings contain three pieces of info. The info itself doesn't really matter but the list of strings is laid out like this:

```
"24,requested,john@email.com"
"22,sent,jane@email.com"
"67,pending,john@email.com"
```

I want to loop through the arraylist and store the first two parts of the string based on the user email. For example the string:

```
"24,requested,john@email.com"
```

I want to store the "24" and "requested" based on the user email "john@email.com". Since the strings won't be of the same length I know I can split the string by the ",". I just don't know what data structure to use to store the information in the way I explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a way in many other available.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class UserInfo {
    int numberId;
    String status;
    String email;

    public UserInfo(int numberId, String status, String email) {
        this.numberId = numberId;
        this.status = status;
        this.email = email;
    }

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserInfo{" +
                "numberId=" + numberId +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    //...
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] entries = {"24,requested,john@email.com", "22,sent,jane@email.com", "67,pending,john@email.com" };

       List<UserInfo> userInfos = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String line : entries) {

            String[] splittedLine = line.split(",");

            String email = splittedLine[2];
            int numberId = Integer.parseInt(splittedLine[0]);
            String status = splittedLine[1];

            UserInfo u = new UserInfo(numberId, status, email);

            userInfos.add(u);
        }

        // you can store on a list
        System.out.println(userInfos);
        // [UserInfo{numberId=24, status='requested', email='john@email.com'}, UserInfo{numberId=22, status='sent', email='jane@email.com'}, UserInfo{numberId=67, status='pending', email='john@email.com'}]

        // or you can group the userInfos by a property
        Map<String, List<UserInfo>> mapUsersByEmail = userInfos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserInfo::getEmail));
        System.out.println(mapUsersByEmail);
        // {
        //   jane@email.com=[
        //     UserInfo{numberId=22, status='sent', email='jane@email.com'}
        //   ],
        //   john@email.com=[
        //     UserInfo{numberId=24, status='requested', email='john@email.com'}, UserInfo{numberId=67, status='pending', email='john@email.com'}
        //   ]
        // }


    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought of turning the info of a user into an object. I was trying to directly store the info into an array or map from the for loop.

Comment: As I said, it's just one of many ways.

You can use a map, set, list, or array to store your data, but you must first think about the structure you need to handle.

Oh, and if you liked my answer, vote for it. This helps me a lot.